# Colorize output from sensors

Tags: text-processing, colors, watch, sensors

I use `sensors` to keep an eye on CPU temperatures on the console. This is part of the output:

```
coretemp-isa-0001
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 1:  +45.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
Core 0:         +39.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
Core 1:         +39.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
Core 2:         +40.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
Core 3:         +38.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
Core 4:         +40.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
Core 8:         +39.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
Core 9:         +38.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
Core 10:        +38.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
Core 11:        +39.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
Core 12:        +39.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)

nouveau-pci-0200
Adapter: PCI adapter
GPU core:     +0.92 V  (min =  +0.92 V, max =  +1.00 V)
fan1:        2220 RPM
temp1:        +48.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, hyst =  +3.0°C)
                       (crit = +105.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)
                       (emerg = +135.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)
```

I would like to 'colorize' this output. In particular, if temperatures are above a certain threshold, I would like them to be shown in red. So, for example, let's say the threshold is 60, then any occurence of `+60.0°C`, `+61.0°C`, `+62.0°C`, and so on should be in red (ideally, I would like an orange level and a red level based on two different thresholds, but a one level solution would be great as well). Ideally, this should also work with `watch sensors`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Usage:** `sensors | ./color_sensors.awk`

**Usage with watch:** `watch -c 'sensors | ./color_sensors.awk'`

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    DEFAULT_COLOR = "\033[;m";
    RED           = "\033[1;31m";
    MAGENTA       = "\033[1;35m";

    # CPU_thresholds
    cpu_high = 60; 
    cpu_middle = 50; 

    # GPU_thresholds
    gpu_high = 80; 
    gpu_middle = 70; 
}

function colorize(temp, mid_trsh, high_trsh) {
    new_color = "";  

    temp_number = temp;
    gsub("[^0-9]","",temp_number);
    gsub(".$","",temp_number);

    if(temp_number >= high_trsh) 
        new_color = RED;
    else if (temp_number >= mid_trsh) 
        new_color = MAGENTA;

    return new_color temp DEFAULT_COLOR;
}

/Core/          { $3 = "\t" colorize($3, cpu_middle, cpu_high); }
/Physical id/   { $4 = "\t" colorize($4, cpu_middle, cpu_high); }
# Multiple spaces added for alignment here - "\t      ".
/temp1/         { $2 = "\t      " colorize($2, gpu_middle, gpu_high) " "; }
                { print; }
```

**Result:**
[image]

Comment: Thanks! I use light text on a black background, but I just adjusted the colors to make this work better for me. Also `watch -c 'sensors | ./color_sensors.awk'` works nicely.

Comment: @Wolfgang I solved the problem with unwanted font color change. Now, script work with any previous font color - manual code change don't needed.

Comment: Great, thanks! Do you see the `temp1: +48.0°C` part under `GPU core`? Is there a way to colorize that one too?

Comment: It's easy, just add one line `/temp1/         { $2 = "\t      " colorize($2) " "; }` in the bottom, after `/Physical id/` line. But I think this temperature value should have own threshold range: like 80 degree - middle, 90 - high, because CPU's 50,60 will be small for GPU. Right? Then, we are needed change `colorize` function for taking custom thresholds in the arguments, like: `colorize(temp, mid_trsh, high_trsh)`. And pass arguments to it, like `colorize($3, 50, 60)` for CPU, and `colorize($2, 80, 90) for GPU`

Comment: I added aforementioned improvements to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, works beautifully. Would upvote more than once if I could.